# How TensorFlow read file from s3 bytestream

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, amazon-s3

I have done a deep learning model in TensorFlow for image recognition, and this one works reading an image file from local directory with `tf.read_file()` method, but I need now that the file be read by TensorFlow since a variable that is a Byte-Streaming that extract the image file since an S3 Bucket of Amazon without storage the streaming in local directory

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pass in the fully formed s3 path to tf.read_file(), like:
`s3://bucket-name/path/to/file.jpeg` where `bucket-name` is the name of your s3 bucket, and `path/to/file.jpeg` is where it's stored in your bucket. It seems possible you might be running into some access permissions issue, depending on if your bucket is private. You can follow https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/community/en/docs/deploy/s3.md to set up your credentials

Is there an error you ran into when doing this?